# Serializing JSON array of foreign keys using sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

If I have a JSON object as follows

```
{
 name: "John Smith",
 tags: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Each number in the tags array above is a foreign key associated with a Tag record.

What's the most efficient way of creating this record using sequelize?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing your relations are like

```
Person.hasMany(Tag);
Tag.hasMany(Person);
```

You could create a Person and later on find those tasks and assign them to him

```
Person.create(obj)
   .success(function (person) {
      Tag.findAll({where: { id: obj.tags }})
         .success(function (tags) {
            person.setTags(tags);
         });
   });
```